# Clean local variables before call another script in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have multiple powershell scripts, calling each other (like a chain: script1 calls script2, which is calling another one...).
I have lost the control of how many local variables have same names in more than one script, so I am getting undesirable values.
What do you recommend to start each script wihout values in local variables?

I have found this solution, but not sure is the best:

```
Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; Remove-Module *; $error.Clear(); Clear-Host
```

Answer (score 0):

As a way to clear the decks it's probably not a bad way to do it, depending on when you call it and what else you're doing within that session. For the variables at least, you can always use

```
Get-Variable *
```

before and after using Remove-Variable to see what variables existed before, and which ones remain afterwards, and seeing if there are any unintended losses.

For instance, if you use $profile to load anything into a new session then your method may also cause those to be cleared.

If the variables are being created in a parent script and you then call Remove-Variable * from one of the scripts down the chain, when the chain of scripts finish and control returns to their parent script those scripts will no longer have access to those variables. That may or may not be an issue for you depending on what you're doing. Using the -scope option on Remove-Variable may help to limit that impact.

A less sweeping method might be to look at which scopes you're using for the variables within your scripts. Those control where the variables are accessible from, and when they're destroyed.

For instance, are you using $global:varname which then makes the variable available globally within the current PowerShell session, not just the current script session, when $varname in the script scope would do?

If you use $varname in both the first script, and one that's called by it (but perhaps for different purposes) it will by default be defined in the Script scope, which makes it available in both the current script and any child scripts. If instead you define it as $private:varname then it will only exist in the current script, and not be inherited by any child script called from it. So for instance each script in the chain could have $private:varname defined, without the value set in one script impacting either child or parent scripts.

You can find quite a good guide on scopes here - https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-scopes.html